# Python: Rename directories with subdirectories

Tags: python, rename

I've read a few other posts and tried the code in those answers but can't get mine to work.

This is my file structure:

```
motherfile g934uth98t
motherfile g934uth98t/kid file fh984bvt34ynt
motherfile g934uth98t/kid file fh984bvt34ynt/something elsee goes here 98573v4985hy4
motherfile g934uth98t/big bad wolf r6b5n656n
```

The goal is:

```
motherfile
motherfile/kid file
motherfile/kid file/something elsee goes here
motherfile/big bad wolf
```

This is my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
    for name in dirs:
        direc = os.path.join(root, name)
        newdirec = '.'
        for part in direc.split('\\')[1:]:
            newdirec += '\\'
            newdirec += ' '.join(part.split()[:-1])
        os.rename(direc,newdirec)
```

Without the os.rename, and using prints (direc then newdirec), it works fine.

```
motherfile g934uth98t
motherfile
motherfile g934uth98t/kid file fh984bvt34ynt
motherfile/kid file
motherfile g934uth98t/kid file fh984bvt34ynt/something elsee goes here 98573v4985hy4
motherfile/kid file/something elsee goes here
motherfile g934uth98t/big bad wolf r6b5n656n
motherfile/big bad wolf
```

However, when it renames, it does the motherfile, but then all the other directories no longer exist (as they're relative to motherfile g934uth98t), so the script ends.

With `topdown=False`, I get an error:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.\\motherfile g934uth98t\\kid file fh984bvt34ynt\\something elsee goes here 98573v4985hy4' -> '.\\motherfile\\kid file\\something elsee goes here'`

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Tried this, still no luck, same error (second one). Perhaps it's a Windows file directory format issue?

```
import os

originaldirs = []
count = 0

def collect():
    global originaldirs
    originaldirs = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
        for name in dirs:
            originaldirs.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    global count
    count += 1

def rename_first():
    target = originaldirs[count]
    print(target)
    newdirec = '.'
    for part in target.split('\\')[1:]:
        newdirec += '\\'
        newdirec += ' '.join(part.split()[:-1])
        newdirec.replace('\\','//')
    # os.rename(target,newdirec)
    print(newdirec)

while True:
    try:
        collect()
        rename_first()
    except IndexError:
        print('Fin')
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(".").glob("**/*"):
    if path.is_dir():
        target = path.parent / " ".join(path.name.split()[:-1]) 
        path.rename(target)
```

Comment: `FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'file' -> '.' `

Comment: I should also mention there are files in this structure too, but I only want it to rename the folders and _not_ the files.

Comment: @Jamesdeluk Updated the snippet. This way only the directories will be renamed, while all the files in any sub-level will be left intact.